# How to prove this inequality in Hilbert Space

Tags: analysis, inequality, hilbert-spaces

This is my first year in Hilbert Spaces and I'm stuck on this simple inequality.

> Prove the next inequality:
>
> $$\left\|\frac 12 (x+y)\right\|^2 \le \frac 12\|x\|^2+ \frac 12\|y\|^2 $$

Could you give me some tip? Any suggestion is helpful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In Hilbert spaces you can write $\|x\|^2$ as $<x,x>$ where $<,>$ is the scalar product. Then try to use the linearity of the scalar product.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite $\|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2$ using the  [parallelogram identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law):

$$\frac12(\|x\|^2 + \|y\|^2) = \frac14(\|x+y\|^2 + \underbrace{\|x-y\|^2}_{\ge 0}) \ge \frac14\|x+y\|^2 = \left\|\frac12(x+y)\right\|^2$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Expand $\left\|\frac12(x+y)\right\|^2$ and use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 0):

By Cauchy   Schwartz we have,
$$ Re\langle x,y\rangle \le |\langle x,y\rangle|\le \|x\|\|y\|$$
thus,

$$\mathrm{||\frac 12 (x+y)||}^2  =\frac 14 (\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2+ 2Re|\langle x,y\rangle ) \le \frac 14 (\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2+ 2\|x\|\|y\|)\\ \le \frac 12\mathrm{||x||}^2+ \frac 12\mathrm{\|y\|}^2$$

Since $$2|ab|\le a^2+b^2$$